# How can I save model weights to mlflow tracking sever using pytorch-lightning?

Tags: pytorch

I would like to save model weights to mlflow tracking using pytorch-lightning.
pytorch-lightning supports [logging](https://williamfalcon.github.io/pytorch-lightning/Trainer/Logging/#mlflow).
However, it seems that saving model weights as a artifact on mlflow is not supported.

At first, I planed to override [ModelCheckpoint](https://github.com/williamFalcon/pytorch-lightning/blob/master/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/pt_callbacks.py#L152) class to do it, but I found it is difficult for me because of complex Mixin operations.

Anybody knows simple way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

As @xela said, you can use the `experiment` object of the mlflow logger to log artifacts.

In case you want to frequently log model weights during training, you could extend [ModelCheckpoint](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/callbacks.html#model-checkpointing):

```py
class MLFlowModelCheckpoint(ModelCheckpoint):
    def __init__(self, mlflow_logger, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mlflow_logger = mlflow_logger

    @rank_zero_only
    def on_validation_end(self, trainer, pl_module):
        super().on_validation_end(trainer, pl_module)
        run_id = self.mlflow_logger.run_id
        self.mlflow_logger.experiment.log_artifact(run_id, self.best_model_path)
```

And then use in your training code

```py
mlflow_logger = MLFlowLogger()
checkpoint_callback = MLFlowModelCheckpoint(mlflow_logger)
trainer = pl.Trainer(checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback, logger=mlflow_logger)
```

Comment: This callback is extremely useful. However, there's one issue that was really difficult to spot. When using DDP and multiple GPUs, the trainer may hang indefinitely. It's because `on_validation_end` - also in the base class - gets called only for the rank zero process. I suggest adding another method (`upload_best_model`) that is decorated with `@rank_zero_only` and calling it from `on_validation_end` (which is executed always).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @stecklin is to use the loggers' [after_save_checkpoint](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.html#pytorch_lightning.loggers.base.LightningLoggerBase.after_save_checkpoint) method.

You could extend [MLFlowLogger](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_lightning.loggers.mlflow.html#pytorch_lightning.loggers.mlflow.MLFlowLogger) like this:

```python
class MLFlowLoggerCheckpointer(pl.MLFlowLogger):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def after_save_checkpoint(self, model_checkpoint: pl.ModelCheckpoint) -> None:
        """
        Called after model checkpoint callback saves a new checkpoint.
        """

        self.experiment.log_artifact(
            self.run_id, model_checkpoint.best_model_path
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it directly in the experiment object?

https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.1/loggers.html#using-loggers